# Run deferred shell command in Make

Tags: makefile

In my Makefile I want to execute multiple steps as a part of a single target. Those steps should be done sequentially, because they depend on one another. This is the simplified case:

```
target:
    git archive --remote=some-remote master --format zip -o ./zipfile.zip
    echo "$(VARIABLE_IN_MAKE):$(shell unzip -z ./zipfilezip | tail -1)" > ./textfile
    $(shell cat ./textfile)
```

The problem here is that the shell command - `$(shell unzip -z ./zipfilezip | tail -1)` is executed as soon as the rule is "loaded", i.e. before the zipfile even exists. That returns errors. The `cat` command is also expanded too early.

What is the *correct* way to execute a subshell not before, but only after all the steps above have finished? Do I have to wrap all the commands in a `bash -c` call? Or chain them via `&&`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get  rid of these `$(shell...)`. Each line of a make recipe is already a shell script:

```
target:
    git archive --remote=some-remote master --format zip -o ./zipfile.zip
    echo "$(VARIABLE_IN_MAKE):$$(unzip -z ./zipfilezip | tail -1)" > ./textfile
    cat ./textfile
```

Note that, in the second line, `$$(unzip -z ./zipfilezip | tail -1)` is expanded twice: a first time by make before passing the recipe to the shell, leading to `$(unzip -z ./zipfilezip | tail -1)`, and a second time by the shell that treats it as a command substitution. This is why the `$$` is needed: to escape the first expansion by make. If you were using `$(unzip -z ./zipfilezip | tail -1)` directly, make would expand it as the empty string (unless you have a make variable which name is `unzip -z ./zipfilezip | tail -1`, but this is very unlikely).

Comment: The double dollar sign is the answer. I swear I tried that but somehow something else must have failed. All is working well now, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Sometimes it's simpler to use the old-school shell backticks inside make recipes...